# Avoid escaping glob expressions in plumbum

Tags: python, shell, glob, expansion, plumbum

Suppose I want to run something like `ls a*` using [plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

```
from plumbum.cmd import ls
ls['a*']()
...
ProcessExecutionError: Command line: ['/bin/ls', 'a*']
Exit code: 1
Stderr:  | ls: a*: No such file or directory
```

I understand plumbum automatically escapes the arguments, which is usually a good thing.  But is there a way to make it understand glob expressions should be passed to the shell as-is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But is there a way to make it understand glob expressions should be passed to the shell as-is?

`plumbum` passes `a*` to `ls` command as-is. `ls` command doesn't run any shell, so there is no glob expansion (it is done by the shell on *nix).

You could use `glob` module to do the expansion:

```
from glob import glob

ls('-l', *glob('a*'))
```

Another way is to use `Workdir` object:

```
from plumbum import local

ls('-l', *local.cwd // 'a*')
```

To defer the call; you could use `ls['-l'][args]` syntax (note: there is probably a bug in `plumbum 1.1.0` version that requires to convert `args` list to a tuple explicitly).

If you want; you could call the shell:

```
from plumbum.cmd import sh

sh('-c', 'ls -l a*')
```

Note: Python's `glob.glob()` function might produce the glob expansion different from that of the shell.

Comment: I was wondering how to handle glob expansion when using `plumbum.SshMachine`. I ended up using something like `remote['sh']('-c', 'ls a*')`

Comment: @PeterGibson check whether the same approach as in the answer works: `remote['ls'](*remote.cwd // 'a*')`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes it does. Actually for my purposes `remote.cwd // 'a*'` by itself may suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You can do your own glob expansion using Python's builtin [`glob` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html). For your example:

```
from plumbum.cmd import ls
from glob import glob

ls[glob('a*')]
```

Comment: There might be a bug in `plumbum 1.1.0` because `ls[glob('a*')]()` fails but `ls[tuple(glob('a*'))]()` works.

Comment: +1. It is fixed on plumbum 1.4.1 i.e., `ls[glob('a*')]()` works (note: the parentheses at the end are there to run the command).

Answer (score 1):

For the special case of ls, there's another way:

```
from plumbum import local

p = local.path('path/to/dir')
local.cwd.glob(str(p) + 'a*')
```

-- or --

```
from plumbum import local

p = local.path('path/to/dir')
local.cwd.chdir(p)
local.cwd.glob('a*')
```